# ¿RecyclerView como pasar los datos a dos layouts diferentes?

Tags: android, kotlin

Buenas tengo dos layouts creados par e impar en forma de tarjeta y quiero que se envien segun sea par o impar la posicion al layout principal que seria el recyclerView y no se como trabajar el adaptador para que sea asi solo consigo enviar los datos a 1 layout .

```
class AdaptadorCustumon(var contexto: Context, items: ArrayList<BookItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCustumon.ViewHolder>() {

  var items:ArrayList<BookItem>? = null
  var viewHolder : ViewHolder? = null
  init {
    this.items = items
  }

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType : Int): AdaptadorCustumon.ViewHolder {

    val vista = LayoutInflater.from(contexto).inflate(R.layout.card_impar, parent,false)

    viewHolder = ViewHolder(vista)

    return  viewHolder!!

  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return this.items?.count()!!
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder :ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = items?.get(position)

    holder.autor?.text = item?.autor
    holder.titulo?.text = item?.titulo
  }

  class ViewHolder(vista : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista){

    var vista = vista

    var autor : TextView? = null
    var titulo : TextView? = null

    init {
      titulo = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo1)
      autor = vista.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de haberte entendido bien. Vos necesitas pasarle la posicion del item que selecciono dentro del recycler a tu activity o fragment que contiene ese recycler para poder luego mostrar si la posicion fue par o impar? va por ahi?
El recycler contiene a los otros dos layouts en forma de tarjeta?
Por favor redactalo un poco mejor, estoy seguro que podremos ayudarte pero se entiende que necesitas exactamente.

Comment: Buenas perdona si esta mal redactado, lo que necesito es que el RecyclerView en vez de coger unicamente un Layout para mostrar , coja dos diferentes alternandolos, primero cargue uno despues otro y que toda la información que en este caso seria una lista de libros se vaya cargando correctamente no que se cargue dos veces por asi decirlo. Resumiendo que si tengo un array donde paso autor y titulo en el recycler view se vea el primer autor con un layout cargado y el segundo autor con otro layout cargado espero que este algo mejor la explicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que queres es usar un layout para items en posiciones par y otro layout para items en posiciones impares vas a tener que hacer uso del parametro `viewType` del `onCreateViewHolder` y asi decidir cual layout debes usar.

Para poder usar el viewType debes implementar en el adapter el metodo de `getItemViewType` donde apartir de la posicion podes devolver el `viewType` que luego usaras en el `onCreateViewHolder`

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
   return position % 2;//0 si es par y 1 si es impar
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType : Int): AdaptadorCustumon.ViewHolder {

    val vista:View
    if (viewType == 0) {
        vista = LayoutInflater.from(contexto).inflate(R.layout.card_par, parent, false)
    }else{
        vista = LayoutInflater.from(contexto).inflate(R.layout.card_impar, parent, false)
    }
    viewHolder = ViewHolder(vista)

    return  viewHolder!!
}
```